# cv2 findcontours treating numpy-tiled image as individual arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I have a map that I am tiling 3 times, and then applying cv2 `findcontours`. Here's the code I'm using:

```
rr,thetar,phir,br520=hdf.rdhdf_3d('/blahblah/testing/br000520.hdf') # loading the data
br520_r1p05=br520[:,:,61]
trp_br520=np.tile(br520_r1p05,3) # tiling the data

ret, th = cv.threshold(trp_br520, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
th=th.astype(np.uint8)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(th, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
conts=sorted(contours, key=len)

# plot it:

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
ax.imshow(trp_br520,cmap='seismic',vmin=-10,vmax=10)
ax.set_title('Tripling array')

colors = plt.cm.plasma(np.linspace(0,1,len(conts)))

for i in range(len(list(conts))):
    ax.scatter(np.asarray(conts[i])[:,0,1],np.asarray(conts[i])[:,0,0],color=colors[i],s=5)
plt.tight_layout()
```

This results in the following image:

[image]

Clearly, despite it being passed one array with the dimensions (180,1080), it's taking the contours of the original image 3 times. I'm at my wits' end here, how can I force cv2 to take the contours of the full array? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You switched the X and Y coordinates in the call to `scatter`. The point coordinates in the contours are (column, row) unlike the standard row-major ordering of the numpy arrays.

Comment: Hi @DanMašek, thanks but that's actually not the problem -- if I switch them, it just rotates the contours sideways. There should only be one set of contours that stretch across the entire image, and instead it's made 3 copies of contours for the original single image.

Comment: Well, that was the problem and solution as it appeared when I tried to take the code provided and turn it into something that would run... I did wonder, why in my case the plot looked taller than in the picture. I admit, I should have known better and not wasted my time. Next time, provide a proper [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem; I had neglected to transpose the original image when feeding it to `np.tile()`. This resulted in the `th` image being turned sideways, and thus the contours were tiling in the wrong direction as well. I guess the main lesson here is to plot every intermediate step as you go, even for code you're familiar with!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have to ask: Was the problem itself apparent from the code that you've posted in your question? Could this answer have been formulated based on the information and code as presented?